# Bind List<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>> to Data Source

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
 public List<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>> Amounts
        {
            set
            {
                dataGridViewAmounts.DataSource = value;
                dataGridViewAmounts.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

I know that I could do this:

```
public List<Amounts> Amounts
            {
                set
                {
                    dataGridViewAmounts.DataSource = value;
                    dataGridViewAmounts.Visible = true;
                }
            }
```

However, I was wandering if it was possible without defining an amounts type.

Comment: Do you get any error when doing this?

Comment: @Guy, nothing appears in the data table.

Comment: Please specify technology used. I guess `winforms` becaue of Data grid view reference. (?)

Comment: @niksofteng, thanks.  I have done that.

Comment: You need to elaborate your requirement more. If you bind list of kv pair without specifying columns for gv at design time, it should work and display 2 columns, key and value. I guess you want to show either `key` or `value` but not both? Also in that case, datagridview is incorrect choice. You should better use `Lisbox` instead.

Comment: @niksofteng, all the values are blank in the grid view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you bind `List<KeyValuePair<T1,T2>>` without specifying column definitions at design time, `DataGridView` will display two columns, one as `Key` and other as `Value`, displaying `decimal`s and `int`s in from `Amounts` list in your case.

I assume you just want to bind and display either of these, not both. You can do so by defining a column, say `Column1` in design mode (check Columns collection in properties window). Then do this:

```
dataGridViewAmounts.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridViewAmounts.DataSource = Amounts;
dataGridViewAmounts.Columns["Column1"].DataPropertyName = "Value"; // Or "Key"
```

**Update**:

See the sample code below:

```
private void DataGridViewWithKVPairList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = GetData();
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"].DataPropertyName = "Value";
}

private List<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>> GetData()
{
    return new List<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<decimal, int>(1.1m, 11),
        new KeyValuePair<decimal, int>(2.1m, 21),
        new KeyValuePair<decimal, int>(3.1m, 31)
    };
}
```

That should give you:

[image]

If you don't define columns at design time, and only do this `dataGridViewAmounts.DataSource = Amounts;` you should get this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I renamed the design time columns and it now works.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can bind anything to a `DataGrid.DataSource` since it is of type `System.Object`. It is of course up to you to then properly use this object type when you are using it in the DataBinding.

You might though want to do something like also storing the value of `Amounts` in a private variable, so that you are able to access it elsewhere on the page if needed.